# Add a field under product name

Tags: product, product-attribute, product-view

I want to add a field in back-end that when I set it, will show in front-end in product page under product name, like picture.

[image]

I define new attribute but in front-end it will show in a table that is in Extra information about product, not under product name.

How can I add this field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` and under the product name at line no 51 echo your attribute.